# Is it possible to animate the appearance and disappearance of a delete button in each listview item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview in my android application, and i want to have a delete button in each item.
I want to show/hide this button  by toggling an external button. Is it possible to do this with an animation? Also the animation has to be synchronized on all items.
I know how to do this without animation but with animation i have no clue.

Does anyone know how to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: You mean each button on each list item will appear and disappear differently ?

Comment: I want that too, but what i want is to show them up all together when i press an external button. When i press this button the animation of the appearance of the button will start in each item at the same time.

Comment: Have a reference to the items button. Then perform the animation on that reference.

Comment: I think there will be a problem with that. The listview performs recycling of views (with convert view). If i keep a reference to a button in the layout of an item it might be used by another item.

Comment: Maybe the correct way would be to have a property inside the adapter, eg. a float [0 - 1] and change this float with a timer and each time to call notifyDataSetChanged(). But i am afraid there would be performance issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a ScrollView that has a LinearLayout inside it. Then by adding rows to it using an inflater for the custom row and inserting each row into the LinerLayout you mock a ListView. It's actually faster for smaller ListViews to do this. Inside your LineraLyout set the android:animateChanges = "true" then add an onClick listener to the button in each row that will remove the view from your LinerLayout you can get the desired effect. It is all in one of the samples on the Android website. If you need source code I can post an example but to see the effect in action look to a sample app I published on Google Play called My Gratitude List that I published to practice some layout effects. Here is [the link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fair.my_gratitude_list) to the app.